# save as csv for class 1, 2 and 3

Tags: python

I have this program

```
# Controlled Assessment - Basic Times Table Test 
import random 
import csv

score = 0

print ("Welcome to the times table test")

name = input("Please type your name: ") 
classnumber = input ("What is your class number?")

print ("How to play") 
print ("Step 1: When you see a question work out the answer and type it in the space.") 
print ("Step 2: Once you have typed your answer press the enter key.") 
print ("Step 3: The program will tell you if you're right or wrong.") 
print ("Step 4: The next question will load and you can repeat from step 1.") 
print ("When you have answered all 10 questions your final score will be printed.")

for q in range(10):
    Number1 = random.randint(1,12)
    Number2 = random.randint(1,12)
    ListOfOperator = ['+','-','*']
    Operator =random.choice(ListOfOperator)
    print ('what is' ,Number1,Operator,Number2)
    Answer= int(input ("Please Type Your Answer: "))

    questionanswer = (Number1,Operator,Number2)

    if Operator == '+':
        realanswer = Number1+Number2
    elif Operator == '-':
        realanswer = Number1-Number2
    elif Operator == '*':
        realanswer = Number1*Number2


    if Answer==realanswer:
        print("Your answer is correct")
        score = score + 1
        print (score)
    else:
        print("Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is.",realanswer,".")
        print (score)
```

Currently I have the following code to save the score with the person's name.

```
    with open ('class 1', 'a') as Class1:
    Class1Writer=csv.writer(Class1)
    Class1Writer.writerow ([name, classnumber])
Class1.close()
```

However this saves to a new file and not the Class1, 2, or 3 files that have already been created, how would I modify the "with open" code so that it would save to the csv file?

```
  with open ('Class3', 'a') as Class3:
     Class3Writer=csv.writer(Class3)
     Class3Writer.writerow ([name, classnumber])
 Class3.close()
```

I now have added if statements for the input but this is saying that class 2 and class 3 are not defined.

> if classnumber == ("1"):
>       with open ('Class1', 'a') as Class1:
>           Class1Writer=csv.writer(Class1)
>           Class1Writer.writerow ([name, classnumber]) Class1.close()
>
> else classnumber == ("2"):
>       with open ('Class2', 'a') as Class2:
>           Class2Writer=csv.writer(Class2)
>           Class2Writer.writerow ([name, classnumber]) Class2.close()
>
> else classnumber == ("3"):
>       with open ('Class3', 'a') as Class3:
>           Class3Writer=csv.writer(Class3)
>           Class3Writer.writerow ([name, classnumber]) Class3.close()

Comment: Why do you have `>` at the start of every line of code?

Comment: That's just how it formatted, do you know how I could fix the second part of code so that it would save to a pre-existing csv file and not a new file each time?

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldnames=['name','classnumber','score']

if os.path.exists('class1.csv'):
    with open('class1.csv', "ab") as csv_file:
        Class1Writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',',dialect='excel',fieldnames=fieldnames)
        Class1Writer.writerow({'name':name,'classnumber':classnumber,'score':score})
else:
    with open('class1.csv', "wb") as csv_file:
        headers = {}
        for n in fieldnames:
              headers[n] = n
        Class1Writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',',dialect='excel',fieldnames=fieldnames)
        Class1Writer.writerow(headers)
        Class1Writer.writerow({'name':name,'classnumber':classnumber,'score':score})
```

Comment: @Mathew Doherty: But please indent your code, for the other users to understand what you are asking. Python is abt indentation...if though not all about...

Comment: If you think i have answered your question, you can accept it as an answer.